# Unable to handle JSON responce in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, json, web-services, cocos2d-x

I want to use web services in my game with the following code:

```
std::vector<char> *dataa = response->getResponseData();
std::string ret(&(dataa->front()), dataa->size());
CCLOG("%s", ("Response message: " + ret).c_str());

ValueMap dict = FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile(ret.c_str());
```

The variable `dict` is assigned the value "nil". Is it possible to get a non-empty `ValueMap` without creating a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a file named the content of ret, so `FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile` isn't going to help you. If you are using XML, you can try `FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromData`.
What you actually need is a JSON parser, I like using [rapidjson](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html). 
Cocos2dx has bundled with rapidjson.

```
#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1
#include "json/document.h"

using namespace rapidjsonl
Document doc;
doc.Parse(ret.c_str());

/* if ret is as follows
{
    "hello": "world",
    "t": true ,
    "f": false,
    "n": null,
    "i": 123,
    "pi": 3.1416,
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
*/
assert(document.HasMember("hello"));
assert(document["hello"].IsString());
log("hello = %s\n", document["hello"].GetString());
```

Comment: Hi, I used 

const char* json = res.c_str();
document.Parse(json);
assert(document.HasMember("city_list"));
assert(document["city_list"].IsString());

printf("hello  city list   cghdisghhbc iuhiubh ibni = %s\n", document["city_list"].GetString());

But it is printing null .

Comment: Check parse error first: `if (d.Parse(json).HasParseError()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError(offset %u): %s\n", 
        (unsigned)d.GetErrorOffset(),
        GetParseError_En(d.GetParseErrorCode()));
    // ...
}`